# Errno::EACCEs...something to do with 'Sprockets'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, errno

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this error that has started appearing in my app? Thanks for any help.

Soemthing to do with...Sprockets? My app was working fine until recently. With regards 'line 9', application.js is in the admin folder, in Assets, as it should be, and I haven't changed the code.

```
Errno::EACCES in Admin/users#index

Showing /home/mycompaq/myapp/app/views/layouts/admin/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Permission denied - /home/mycompaq/myapp/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2Fb250691303afe8bdea5daa9e24412c8020130818-2524-njp18c-0 or /home/mycompaq/myapp/tmp/cache/assets/D5C/180/sprockets%2Fb250691303afe8bdea5daa9e24412c80
Extracted source (around line #9):

6:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : admin_area_title %></title>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/application", :media => "all" %>
9:     <%= javascript_include_tag "admin/application" %>
10:     <% if @include_goole_maps %>
11:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
12:     <% end %>
Rails.root: /home/mycompaq/myapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/admin/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_admin_application_html_erb___1652810648_69910752274140'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution. Just deleted the tmp folder and its contents in my application folder with:

```
rm -r tmp
```

Probably a good idea to back it up elsewhere, first, just in case.